# How to generate all the vectors between two given ｍ-tuple vectors?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

Assume that we are given two vectors:

 Ａ＝（ａ₁，ａ₂，...，ａₘ）and Ｂ＝（ｂ₁，ｂ₂，...，ｂₘ）

and we need to do something for all the vectors between these two ones.

For example, for Ａ＝（１,１,０）and Ｂ＝（１,２,２）, all the vectors between Ａ and Ｂ are: ｛（１,１,１）,（１,１,２）,（１,２,０）,（１,２,１）｝.

An obvious way to generate such vectors is using ｍ loops (`for` loop), but probably it is not the best one. I would like to know if someone has some better idea.

Comment: As you can see , there is no TEX support. Cosnider adding images of th equations or writting them with a different format

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks. I made some corrections. Is here the right place to ask such a question?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by "an obvious way" because it isn't to me. And really, what do you mean by "do something for all the vectors between these two ones". Any algorithm associates to your problem?

Comment: @Y.Chang Imagine that you need to generate the vectors between A = (1, 1) and B = (2, 3). In this case, using the for loops, you may write the code as for i=1:2 for j=1:3 .... end end. This is what I meant by the obvious method for generating such vectors.

Comment: @Y.Chang And by "do something..." I meant that I need to do some calculations on those vectors. In fact, it is important for me to generate the vectors in a more efficient way than using the for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fixed method. Returns a matrix where each row is one of the vectors of the result.

```
% Data
A = [0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 2]
B = [4, 8, 5, 7, 9, 6]

% Preallocate
b = cell(1,numel(A));
vec = cell(1,numel(A));

% Make a vector of values of each element of the result
for i = 1:numel(A)
    vec{i} = A(i):B(i);
end

% Get all combinations using ndgrid
[b{:}] = ndgrid(vec{:});
b=cat(ndims(b{1})+1,b{:});

% Reshape the numel(A)+1 dimensional array into a 2D array
res = reshape(b,numel(b)/length(A),length(A));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. But, I think it is good for a very special case. For example, I think if I change A as A = [2, 3, 5], then your approach does not conclude the correct solution. Actually, as I understood, your approach gives the correct answer when all the entities in the vectors are the same and as well the distance between the entities in vectors A and B are one. Do you have some idea for generating the vectors between for example A =(0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 2) and B = (4, 8, 5, 7, 9, 6).

Comment: I think I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks again for your attempt. I think something is not working well in your proposed technique. I tried it for A = [0, 1, 1] and B = [1, 1, 3] and the following solutions are obtained  0     0     0, 1     1     1, 1     1     1, 1     1     1, 1     2     3, 1     2     3, which are not the right solutions. I am trying to find out the problem. By the way, it seems really nice technique. I appreciate it.

Comment: replace the cell2mat line with: b=cat(ndims(b{1})+1,b{:});

Comment: @David According to Jed's suggestion, you may edit your solution to be complete.